# Как передать ofstream в поток thread в качестве аргумента?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Вот так выглядит стартовая функция потока:

```
    void printHeapInFile(std::ofstream& ofs, Heap& treeOfEmployees)
    {
        ofs << treeOfEmployees;
    }
```

Так перегружен `operator<<()`

```
std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& ofs, Heap& employees)
{
    for (EmployeeWithKey x : employees._treeOfEmployees)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(employees.writeOrRead);
        ofs << x._empl;
    }
return ofs;
}
```

Так выглядит запуск потока:

```
    std::fstream fout;
    fout.open("result.txt");
    std::thread secondThread(printHeapInFile, std::move(fout), std::ref(treeOfEmployees));
    secondThread.join();
    fout.close();
```

Компилятор ругается так:

```
Ошибка  C2672   "std::invoke": не найдена соответствующая перегруженная функция ThirdTask   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr\xthread  240 
Ошибка  C2893   Сбой при специализации функции-шаблона "unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)"    ThirdTask   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr\xthread  240
```

Я так понимаю, ошибка в том, что я поток записи в файл как-то неправильно передаю потоку thread?

Comment: std::ref(fout) тоже не работает.
Пока пытаюсь разобраться с потоками буквально на ощупь :)

Comment: У вас явно ругается на ThirsTask - а о нем у вас ни слова. Где именно ругается компилятор? Да, он уводит вглубь шаблонов, но строка, которая к этому привела - тоже компилятором указывается. Что это за строка?

Comment: Вы передаете `std::fstream` а функция принимает `std::ofstream`. Перепешите ее чтобы принимана либо `std::fstream` как есть, либо  `std::ostream`.

Comment: @Harry ThirdTask это название проекта. Если закомментировать вывод в файл и оставить только вывод в консоль, то всё работает как нужно.

Ругается именно на эту строку : `std::thread secondThread(printHeapInFile, std::move(fout), std::ref(treeOfEmployees));`

Comment: @VTT Ох. Банальная и глупая опечатка... И правда, теперь всё работает, спасибо!